# Почему не смёрджились правки?

Tags: поддержка, правки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1389041/revisions

[image: скриншот ревизий]

Comment: Потому что между правками было действие (конкретно, ответ от Проста Miha)

Comment: @andreymal, а разве ответы считаются? Я думал, только комментарии.

Comment: У меня нет точной инфы на этот счёт, но по крайней мере это выглядит логичным